# Updated SharePoint Solution not recognized

Tags: web-part, deployment, feature-upgrade

I've modified a minor bug in a User Control of a custom SharePoint solution that was initially deployed on SharePoint 2007 but now it is deployed on SharePoint 2010.

I was hoping to just update the affected parts of the solution, so I copied all the dlls and user controls to the web application virtual folder, I made sure I didn't forget files in Features folder under 14 hive, and I restarted the server.

However, the changes I made are not being recognized at all. I thought of deactivating and re-activating the feature but I can't see it neither in Farm or Site collection features lists. This is actually the same case on the production server. But the front end works fine both on the production and development servers except for that small bug I mentioned above. Also Visual Studio is not showing any debug or build errors.

Please suggest any idea.

Thank you!

Ahmed

Comment: I highly recommend that you upgrade the project to Visual Studio 2010 and take advantage of the packaging and deployment features.  Manually deploying files and web parts to a SharePoint server is very difficult to support even in small environments.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I'm actually using Visual Studio 2010. I thought if I use its deployment tool it will replace everything which isn't what I want to do. Is it possible to just replace the needed files?

Sorry but my knowledge is just a beginner in SharePoint.

Comment: I'm struggling to come up with a good answer, because it is difficult to figure out how it was originally deployed.

Comment: I've no idea too. The whole thing was developed by someone long time ago. Mike, usually is it OK to just replace the assemblies by copy & paste or there's a procedure for that? 

I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: @AhmedJabar have you resolved this situation?